# How to install freestyle stroke shader script to Blender 2.8

Tags: python, scripting

Here is the link that directs me to a script.
http://freestyle.sourceforge.net/GALLERY/python.php?filename=CARTOON/disney.py&headerfilename=pythonheader.txt

I have tried to copy and paste this python script in text editor but will not work. Has anyone figured out how to install this?

Comment: From the related [FAQ](https://freestyleintegration.wordpress.com/frequently-asked-questions-faq/) _"The Freestyle integration into Blender is still ongoing, and its results are expected to be included into Blender 2.5."_  You may need to grab a copy of blender 2.49 and build the Freestyle module as instructed.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work without a bit of reverse-engineering. The modules have different names, and they have a few Blender-specific calls.. Check out your `[Blender installation directory]/scripts/freestyle/styles` for Blender examples.. and the [Blender Freestyle API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/freestyle.html).

You've probably already been there, but the [background reading](http://maverick.inria.fr/Publications/2004/GTDS04/linedrawing_electronicversion.pdf) makes for a good start, if you're trying to get your head round other people's code.